# Spring @Requestmapping class level multiple

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring framework to create api.
I want two urls defined at the class level

```
@RequestMapping({"/jobs","/subs"})
```

and I want to call method 1 when the url is `/host:port/jobs`
and I want to call method 2 when the url is `/host:port/subs`

Is there a way to do this ?

I could remove the mapping at the class level and define it on the method level but I do not want to do that as I don't want to have to define the mapping for all the other methods.

Comment: not possible. Define `RequestMapping` for each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @PathVariable

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "/{whichOne}")
> public class someController {
>     @RequestMapping
>     public ResponseObject someMethod(@PathVariable("whichOne") String whichOne) {
>         switch (whichOne) {
>             case "jobs":
>                 return resolveJobs();
>             case "subs":
>                 return resolveSubs();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But I don't recommend you to do that. Two methods with two request mappings is correct way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help but if you use a path variable then you will have issues using HATEOAS Links by calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't want to have to define the mapping for all the other methods.
```

What do you mean? Just like any other class, You can have methods in the controller class which doesn't map to any URL pattern.

I think there is some flaw in the design here. I would rather add this mapping at the method level and have 2 separate methods handle this.

Comment: What I meant was that other methods will have partial urls to be appended to the class level url.

Answer (score 0):

It is really ugly, but you can do it with this trick:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/jobs", "/subs" })
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String url = request.getRequestURI().toString();

        if (url.endsWith("jobs")) { // or contains
            return getJobs(request);
        }

        // subs
        return getSubs(request);
    }

    private String getJobs(HttpServletRequest request) {
        [...]
        return "jobs";
    }

    private String getSubs(HttpServletRequest request) {
        [...]
        return "subs";
    }
}
```

Comment: Only problem is that the sub methods have partial urls too. But I will try this with a change of design. Thanks for your help.